# How to avoid GLUT window getting activated on mouse hover

Tags: python, hover, mouse, glut, activation

In the following Python program, using PyOpenGL and GLUT, the successive GLUT windows are getting activated merely by the mouse hovering over them.
How can I avoid that?

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

glutInit ()
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGB)
glutInitWindowSize (600, 400)

def displayFunc ():
    glClearColor (1, 1, 1, 1)       
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)   

windows = []
for i in range (3):
    window = glutCreateWindow ('GLUT window {0}'.format (i))
    glutDisplayFunc (displayFunc)

glutMainLoop ()
```

I am using Windows Vista, Python 2.7 and PyOpenGL 3.0.2

Comment: Isn't that usually handled by the window manager?

Comment: I guess so, but I can't find anything in the docs of glut on how to influence it...

Comment: From what I've seen, if it's something handled by the window manager, you **can't**. For instance I use awesomewm on linux, and it will always force the window to do what awesomewm wants to do.